# Redireccionar WEB que usa un iframe mio a mi web

Tags: php, javascript

Hoy me di cuenta que hay varias webs usando iframes de partes de mis dominios, y me interesaría poder poner algún script PHP o JavaScript para redireccionar toda esa gente a mi web.

```
$enlace_actual = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ($enlace_actual != 'http://miweb.com') {

    # todo el contenido de la web + script para redireccionar...
}
```

Pero esto no me funciona como quiero.

Comment: con javascript `if (window.top != window.self) { window.top.location.replace(window.self.location.href); }` es una técnica común

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar javascript con la sentencia:

```
document.location.href="url";
```

Y para devolverte la sentencia puedes poner `document.location.href` de esa manera puedes poner una condición.

**Ejemplo:**

Solución más completa abajo

```
<script>
(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(document.location.href!="http://miweb.com"){
            document.location.href="http://miweb.com";
        }
    },5000);
})();
</script>
```

Ejecuta pasados 5 segundos del evento "`ready`" del documento una comprobación si el href es `http://miweb.com` y si no lo es le lleva allí.

> Si tienes más contenido en tu web (`http://miweb.com/saludos`) puedes utilizar `string.startsWith(string2)` para comprobar si empieza por tu dominio

**Editado 1:**

Para hacer un re-direccionamiento `target="_top"` puedes utilizar

```
window.top.location.replace(window.self.location.href);
```

**Problemas:**

La forma de comprobar correctamente si la página en la que estás es la correcta, no es `document.location.href` (te devuelve el href del iframe), sino que sería `window.top.location.href` y lo que sucede es que está protegido por:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Para comprobarlo realmente tendrías que comprobar todo el objeto entero de `window.top.location` y compararlo con `!==` ya que sino sigue saltando el error. Lo único que se me ocurre sería hacer un php que te devuelva un array de las páginas donde los vas ha hacer iframe (Y puede ser muy tedioso)

**Editado 2:**

En vez de intentarlo por javascript puedes añadir cabeceras a tus servidores como [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) y [Frame-Ancestors](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#frame-ancestors) (Para la Frame-Antecetors recomiendo ver la [página en inglés](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#frame-ancestors) ya que falta contenido)

Comment: Bien, funciona, pero todavia le falta algo, mira, yo tengo dos webs, una que uso como almacenamiento, es decir, guardo archivos php, html, css, javascript,css, etc... Y desde la otra web hago iframes de esos archivos, tendria que permitir dos dominios, https://web1.com y https://web2.com y que las demas webs que no son esas dos, las redirecciona a "web2" que es la principal, y eso no lo logre hacer, probe esto: `if(document.location.href!="web1.com" || "web2.com"` y no funciona. Luego el otro problema, es que la web carga adentro del iframe, y yo quiero que haga como un `target="_top"`

Comment: ...............

Comment: Edite la pregunta al día siguiente. Pero si quieres seguir utilizando el mismo sistema tienes que volver a poner `document.location.href`. Sería `document.location.href!="web1.com"||document.location.href!="web2.com"` El problema aquí es que `document.location.href` muestra la localización del iframe y por eso edite mi pregunta